# Display multiple items on the same slide in Bootstrap Carousal with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display 3 posts (from a Wordpress Custom Post Type) on the same slide inside a Bootstrap Carousel

I integrated the carousel into Wordpress and it's fetching and displaying the posts, one post per slide.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide">
        <!-- Carousel items -->

        <div class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide" id="eventCarousel" data-interval="0">
            <div class="carousel-inner onebyone-carosel">
                <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'services',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1
                );
                $services_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                $services_count = wp_count_posts('services');
                ?>

                <?php

                if ( $services_loop->have_posts() ) :
                    while ( $services_loop->have_posts() ) : $services_loop->the_post();

                        $service_icon = get_field('service_icon');

                        ?>
                        <div class="item <?php if( $services_loop->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() ) { echo 'active'; } ?>">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                                <div class="box">
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <div class="image">
                                            <i class="<?php echo $service_icon; ?>"></i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="info">
                                            <h3 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                            <p>
                                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                            </p>
                                            <div class="more">
                                                <a href="#" title="Title Link">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-3x"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="space"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                endif; ?>
            </div>

            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <?php for ( $i = 1; $i < $services_count->publish; $i++ ) : ?>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?= $i ?>"></li>
                <?php endfor; ?>
            </ol>
        </div>

        <!--/carousel-inner-->
    </div>
```

But when I add this jQuery snippet which came with the carousel, it starts displaying 3 posts per slide.

The problem is, it's cloning the posts with the `clone()` method in order to display multiple posts on the same slide. So when I'm on the first slide, I can see 3 items, let's say `1`, `2` and `3`

When I click on the second slide, I see `2`, `3`, and `4` when instead, it should be showing me `4`, `5` and `6` on the second slide.

How can I fix this?

I don't quite understand what this jQuery snippet is exactly doing, it has something to do with childs and siblings. I understand the pseudo-element `:first-child` will fetch the first element of the whole bunch.

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
})
$('.fdi-Carousel .item').each(function () {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length > 0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
    else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you NEED to use bootstrap carousel? There are others out there that will allow you to set the scroll count meaning it will scroll 3 at a time and achieve what you want. Bootstrap doesn't appear to have this option.

Comment: No, I don't need bootstrap, I can work with any other plugin. I've tried `slick.js` it worked but it breaks down on mobile view and I couldn't fix that issue. I will use any carousel that works with Wordpress Posts.

Comment: Try flickity.js - the best I've used.

Comment: I use owl carousel, but slick does the job as well (if you set them right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you aren't tied down to using bootstrap, try [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/). You have the ability to use the [pagination plugin](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/plugins/pagination/) which allows you to do something like:

```
$('.jcarousel-pagination').jcarouselPagination({
    'perPage': 3
});
```

This sets the page to be 3 items, when scrolling to the next *page* it will start at item number 4.

This shouldn't cause issues with the Wordpress layout as you can wrap all your markup in whatever tags / classes you need.

Comment: I've integrated it and it works fine on desktop view, but when I resize the browser to mobile view, the layout of the carousel doesn't change, it keeps displaying 3 items per slide. http://i.imgur.com/MMWPO6X.jpg

Comment: I think this is the `fullPage.js` plugin messing it all up.

Comment: Yup, I just tested it with `onepage.js` instead of `fullPage.js` and it works flawlessly. Finally, I was able to pinpoint the source of the problem and get the carousel to work.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!